# How do i split a python list element without creating a sublist

Tags: python

I am trying to extract some info from a line of text from a log file, the line has a few odd separators which I can get around with split/replace/join etc.

The issue comes when I try to then split the second time element at the '-' and add it back to the list, I end up with a sublist - which is not what I want.

```
line='2016-05-06T12:00:00.128189+01:00 mac-68c90b45b51e debug: 03959725-10:59:57.250[51222]*** NEW STATUS [3896374] : id=15 object=1 row=00408280 speed=0 crit=2 cell=130 intracell=512'

line1=(" ".join(line.split()).replace('[', '.').replace(']', ' ').strip().split())
```

Results in;

```
['2016-05-06T12:00:00.128189+01:00', 'mac-68c90b45b51e', 'debug:', 03959725-10:59:57.250.51222', '***', 'NEW', 'STATUS', '.3896374', ':', 'id=15', 'object=1', 'row=00408280', 'speed=0', 'crit=2', 'cell=130', 'intracell=512']
```

When I then try to split '03959725-10:59:57.250.51222' with

```
line1[3]=line1[3].replace('-', ' ').split()
```

I end up with;

```
['2016-05-06T12:00:00.128189+01:00', 'mac-68c90b45b51e', 'debug:', ['03959725', '10:59:57.250.51222'], '***', 'NEW', 'STATUS', '.3896374', ':', 'id=15', 'object=1', 'row=00408280', 'speed=0', 'crit=2', 'cell=130', 'intracell=512']
```

What I would like is;

```
    ['2016-05-06T12:00:00.128189+01:00', 'mac-68c90b45b51e', 'debug:', '03959725', '10:59:57.250.51222', '***', 'NEW', 'STATUS', '.3896374', ':', 'id=15', 'object=1', 'row=00408280', 'speed=0', 'crit=2', 'cell=130', 'intracell=512']
```

Any ideas on how to tidy up the way I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use slice assignment:

```
line1[3:4]=line1[3].replace('-', ' ').split()
```

It will replace the slice with given sequence:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> l[3:4] = ['new', 'items']
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 'new', 'items', 5]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it replace the line1[4]?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir: No. `line1[4]` is not included in the slice.

Comment: Such a simple answer, shows I have much to learn, thanks for your help, solution worked perfectly.

Comment: @EdwardHickinbotham You're welcome, I'm glad it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you have Python3.5, there's also this fun way:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 'hello world whats up?', 4, 5]
>>> n = 3
>>> [*a[:n], *a[n].split(), *a[n+1:]]
[0, 1, 2, 'hello', 'world', 'whats', 'up?', 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Reconstruct the list like this:

```
line1 = line1[0:3] + line1[3].replace('-', ' ').split() + line1[4:]
```